# How to reset an Android application states when upgrading / updating

Tags: android, upgrade

I have applications already published on the market. When users download the new version, I want the application to clean all its previous states ( SharedPreferences , SQLite schema ... ). That'd be **equivalent to uninstall the application first then install the new version**.
I read various solutions to

SharedPreferences
[Android: How to reset FirstRun SharedPreferences when my app is updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726283/android-how-to-reset-firstrun-sharedpreferences-when-my-app-is-updated)

SQLiteOpenHelper
[SQLiteOpenHelper onUpgrade() Confusion Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505900/sqliteopenhelper-onupgrade-confusion-android)

But I want one solution to all these problems. Just wonder if it is possible to trigger a "clean states" when the application is being upgraded from the market ?

Comment: The "onUpgrade" method is your solution you can clean all the db and create it again, I use it it works really good with ormLite