# How can I detect if the user is opening the app for the first time after an update?

Tags: android

I need to display release notes after every update just no the first run. How can I implement that?

Comment: Simple update the SharedPreference for First time application open.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to reset FirstRun SharedPreferences when my app is updated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726283/android-how-to-reset-firstrun-sharedpreferences-when-my-app-is-updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read the version number of your manifest with this:

```
String pkgName = mContext.getPackageName();
int versionCode = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pkgName, 0).versionCode;
```

save it (in SharedPreferences for example) and compare the two values when the app is launched

Answer (score 0):

Add in your code checking of some new key - for example:

```
if (preferences.contains("update-1.1"){
  // first start after update
  // ...
  preferences.edit().putBoolean("update-1.1").commit();
} else{
  // not first start
}
```